# My php and form will not connect to my database to add values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, modal-dialog

I have created a form using Bootstrap modal, a database connection via PHP as well as a simple form validation. When I fill out form and hit submit, it seems to connect to database and no form errors come back. It states: "-1 rows are affected. Thank you for your RSVP" but when I look on PHPMyAdmin there are no values inputted into my database.

Below is my PHP:

```
<?php

//check if form is submitted and not a hack/bot. Checks to see if form is submitte by the post method then runs fxn. 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    //grab all values that come from form in these variables. Each line below grabs info typed/selected in each form input. The value in square brackets is the name value of each input. Keep the $variables different from input names.   
    $rsvpvar = $_POST['rsvpBox'];
    $fullnamevar = $_POST['fullName'];
    $emailvar = $_POST['emailBox'];
    $attendvar = $_POST['attend'];
    $guestsvar = $_POST['extraGuests'];
    $commentsvar = $_POST['additionals'];

    //If fxn checks to see if all above variables have values stored in them using !empty fxn and if not if runs the echo. Use !empty (not empty) and not isset because isset will allow db connection even if some form values are blank. If there is a value stored in all form inputs then we incude this php or run the connetion to database.
    if(!empty($rsvpvar) && !empty($fullnamevar) && !empty($emailvar) && !empty($attendvar) && !empty($guestsvar) && !empty($commentsvar)){

        //Define the below vaiables within parenthesis.
        $hostname = "rsvp.db";
        $username = "******";
        $password = "******";
        $dbname = "rsvp";

        //Connection to mysql database. OR die drops connection to database for security reasons. Connect error gives message.
        $dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) OR die("Could not connect to database, ERROR: ".mysqli_connect_error());

        //Set encoding
        mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");

        //insert into table "rsvp" by getting or querying values stored in $dbc variable (db info). You insert into the corresponding rows of the db table (i.e. RSVP), then you grab what you're inserting using the VALUES. What you're inserting comes from the above variables.
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO rsvp(RSVP, FULLNAME, EMAIL, ATTEND, GUESTS, COMMENTS) VALUES('$rsvpvar', '$fullnamevar', '$emailvar', '$attendvar', $guestsvar', '$commentsvar')");

        //define variable $registered which checks database to make sure values were inserted and rows were affected then outputs how many rows affected. Make sure the $dbc or connection info is inside parenthesis.
        $registered = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
        echo $registered." rows are affected. Thank you for your RSVP";

    }else{
        echo "ERROR: You did not fill out each section";
    }
}else{
    echo "Please fill out everything on the RSVP form";
}
```

?>

and my html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">RSVP</h2>
                </div>
                <form role="form" method="post" action="php/rsvp.php">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-inline row response">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2>Ya Comin'?</h2>
                                <div class="radio-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpBox" id="attending" value="option1">
                                        I'll be there with bells on!
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio-inline">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <input type="radio" name="rsvpBox" id="notAttending" value="option2">
                                        Sorry, wish I was cooler...
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="deets row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2>Your Deets</h2>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control" id="fullName" placeholder="FULL NAME">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="emailBox" class="form-control" id="emailBox" placeholder="EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM">
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row days">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2>Days Attending</h2>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="attend" value="option1">
                                        Friday: Rehersal Dinner &amp; Beach Party
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="attend" value="option2">
                                        Saturday: Wedding &amp; Reception
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="guests row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2>Number of Additional Guests</h2>
                                <select id="extraGuests" name="extraGuests" class="form-control">
                                  <option>1</option>
                                  <option>2</option>
                                  <option>3</option>
                                  <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extras row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <h2>Anything Else?</h2>
                                <h4>Main Course Served Will be Chicken</h4>
                                <div class="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="message"></label>
                                        <textarea name="additionals" id="additionals" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Food specifications, allergies, guest names, etc..."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help as I am not an expert on databases...

Comment: Ahm you declare the as $xxxvar and then you ask if $XXX is not empty. $XXX is not even set in your code so yeah its empty, you have to ask for the right variables with the "var" at the end and all lowercase.

Comment: Also i hope you know your code is dangerous and vulreanble to SQL injections. The worst case scenario is a "hacker" deletes or leakes your DB with whatever informations in it.

Comment: Thank you @KoalaGangsta I have since updated my asked variables to equal my declared ones and I still receive the same error. This is not my complete code. I do plan to make it secure for SQL injections before going live. Thanks

Comment: The `-1` returned by `mysqli_affected_rows` means that there was an error, so use the [mysqli_error_list](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php) to check what's wrong.
As @KoalaGangsta said, your code allows SQL injection, and this could actually be the reason of this error (ie. if you test your form placing in any of the fields a quote character `'` or a backslash at the end, breaking the query).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I will complete the security measures before uploading. Would I get rid of the threat if I delete the database on phpmyadmin and start over with updated code?

Answer (score 1):

Your all `POST` variable is :

```
$rsvpvar = $_POST['attending'];
$emailvar = $_POST['emailBox'];
$fullnamevar = $_POST['fullName'];
$attend1var = $_POST['friday'];
$attend2var = $_POST['saturday'];
$guestsvar = $_POST['extraGuests'];
$commentsvar = $_POST['additionals'];
```

SO, should be condition  :

```
if(!empty($rsvpvar) && !empty($emailvar) && !empty($fullnamevar) && !empty($attend1var) && !empty($attend2var) && !empty($guestsvar) && !empty($commentsvar)){
```

Please use same name in 2 radio input field :

```
<input type="radio" name="attending" id="attending" value="option1" checked>.
<input type="radio" name="attending" id="notAttending" value="option2">
```

Note :  your code is open for [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have corrected my !empty variables to correspond with the previously declared variables in the POST section and still receive the same error...

Comment: ok, please use same name your input radio like `<input type="radio" name="attending" id="attending" value="option1" checked>.
<input type="radio" name="attending" id="notAttending" value="option2">`

Comment: No unfortunately not. Still won't submit to database. Could it be the way the checkbox or dropdown is setup? Because it keeps saying to fill out all fields in form even when I do.

Comment: you put only one condition `if(!empty($emailvar)){` just fot test. and add a space your insert query after `rsvp` table  name `INSERT INTO rsvp (RSVP`